# How can i change datetime format in sql?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, t-sql

How can i change dateformat?Forexample:

2009-06-10 10:16:41.123

->2009-June

2009-05-10 10:16:41.123

->2009-May

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
select cast(datepart(year, mydatecolumn)  as char(4)) + '-' 
   + datename(month, mydatecolumn)
from mytable
```

Answer (score 2):

You should not change the date-format in your database.
You should just make sure that , when displaying the date, you correctly format the date, so that you display them in the format that you want.

How to do that, is related to the language you use in your program.
You can also output the date directly in the format you want using the method of ck.

Comment: I second that. Formatting should never be done in the data layer, it's a localisation nightmare.

Answer (score 0):

To interpret input use [SET DATEFORMAT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189491.aspx)

To cast to character, see the [CONVERT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx) styles.

To format output, use whatever your client environment uses to format output, SQL itself has no output but [TDS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tabular_Data_Stream) and display is left to the client.

Answer (score 0):

Its a pain to do custom formats without writing your own function.

best i have is 
SELECT NewFormat = YEAR(GETDATE()) + '-' + DATENAME(month, GETDATE())

Comment: You will also have to convert the YEAR to NVARCHAR 
CAST(YEAR(GETDATE()) AS NVARCHAR(10))